# different aws sdks and the use of `@` in require

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

What's the difference between `aws-sdk` and `@aws-sdk/client-s3`

I saw different codes in javascript and some libraries have the `@` symbol infront of them, for aws, I saw:

```
var aws = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
```

What's the difference between the two syntax and are they relatable?(e.g. the first syntax is referring to something inside of the `aws-sdk` library?) and what's the use/meaning/purpose of the `@` symbol while importing a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aws = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
```

The above code snippet is an example of AWS JavaScript SDK v3

---

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
```

The above code snippet is an example of AWS JavaScript SDK v2

---

> what's the use/meaning/purpose of the `@` symbol while importing a library

From the reference linked below:

> In v3 of AWS SDK for JavaScript, we achieved modularity by breaking the JavaScript SDK core into multiple packages and publishing each service as its own package. These packages are published under @aws-sdk/ scope on NPM to make it easy to identify packages that are part of the official AWS SDK for JavaScript.

---

**Reference:**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/modular-packages-in-aws-sdk-for-javascript/